# Reading text in word with Style/format using c#

Tags: c#, office-interop

i am writing a c# code to open a word file using Application and Document object and want to read a document with its styling and formats example is given below:-
i am able to getting text but not able to getting its styles and formats.

```
private void readFileContent(string path)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    object file = path;
    object nullobj = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(
        ref file, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
        ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
        ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
        ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);


    doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
    doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();

    IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();

    string getdata = data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();

    doc.Close(ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);
    wordApp.Quit(ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my mind this endeavour is well beyond the powers of Interop. I suggest using the [Open Xml Sdk](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124) for such a task since it's much more powerful and does not bear all the Interop limitations. The solution is straightforward.

```
  using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
  using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
  // read-only open 
  using (var document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(@"Your.docx", false))
  {
   // Gets the MainDocumentPart of the WordprocessingDocument 
   var main = document.MainDocumentPart;
    // document fonts
    var fonts = main.FontTablePart;
    // document styles
    var styles = main.StyleDefinitionsPart;
    var effects = main.StylesWithEffectsPart;
    // root element part of the doc
    var doc = main.Document;
    // actual document body
    var body = doc.Body;
    // styles on paragraps
    foreach (Paragraph para in body.Descendants<Paragraph>()
      .Where(e => e.ParagraphProperties != null&& e.ParagraphProperties.ParagraphStyleId != null))
      Console.WriteLine("Text:{0}->Style name:{1}", para.InnerText, para.ParagraphProperties.ParagraphStyleId.Val);
    // styles on Runs
    foreach (Run run in body.Descendants<Run>()
      .Where(r => r.RunProperties != null && r.RunProperties.RunStyle != null))
      Console.WriteLine("Text: {0}->Run style: {1}", run.InnerText, run.RunProperties.RunStyle.Val );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only getting the text:

```
string getdata = data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();`.
```

Getting all Word formatting will involve a LOT more work. I would suggest trying to get the result as Html or Rtf, which will preserve most common formatting:

```
string getdata = data.GetData(DataFormats.Rtf).ToString();
```

Also, please note that using Interop this way is not recommended unless there is a user actually present when the application is running. Word might pop up a dialog box (for example, "This file is locked by user X"), so if you're running this code on a server somewhere, you're in trouble.